# IF filter for regex R

Tags: r, regex, if-statement

I'd like to create a flag in a data frame (or data table) based on a stringi match to some terms in R.

```
df = data.frame(text = c("AABA","AACA","AAAA","BAAE","CAAD","CCCC","DDDD","EEEE"))
df$flag[stri_detect_regex(df$text,"AAB|AAC|AAA|BAA|CAA")] = 'Match1'
```

Showing output like this:

```
    text    flag
1   AABA    Match1
2   AACA    Match1
3   AAAA    Match1
4   BAAE    Match1
5   CAAD    Match1
6   CCCC    <NA>
7   DDDD    <NA>
8   EEEE    <NA>
```

I then want to check for another pattern:

```
df$flag[stri_detect_regex(df$text,"CCCC|DDDD")] = 'Match2'
```

But only run this if flag is NA ie is.na(df$flag).  It would also be great to know if how I could include multiple conditions, ie

```
is.na(df$flag) & df$other_var == 1
```

The reason I want to do this is I need to review many millions of rows and only want to do the regex on rows that either don't have a flag already and/or include other filter criteria.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
df %>%
   mutate(flag = case_when(stri_detect_regex(text, "AAB|AAC|AAA|BAA|CAA") ~ "Match1",
                           stri_detect_regex(text, "CCCC|DDDD") ~ "Match2"))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, that solution works, curiously though its only very slightly quicker than running the 2 stringi matches individually, for just under 400K matches this takes 9.3 seconds, where the 2 individual matches take 9.4 seconds. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

You could used named capture groups and extract the name

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("AABA","AACA","AAAA","BAAE","CAAD","CCCC","DDDD","EEEE"))

capture_name <- function(x) {
  x <- attr(x, 'capture.start')
  ifelse(sum(x) == 0, NA, colnames(x)[x > 0])
}

p <- c(Match1 = 'AAB|AAC|AAA|BAA|CAA',
       Match2 = 'CCCC|DDDD')
p <- paste(sprintf('(?<%s>%s)', names(p), p), collapse = '|')

within(df, {
  flag <- sapply(gregexpr(p, df$text, perl = TRUE), capture_name)
})

#   text   flag
# 1 AABA Match1
# 2 AACA Match1
# 3 AAAA Match1
# 4 BAAE Match1
# 5 CAAD Match1
# 6 CCCC Match2
# 7 DDDD Match2
# 8 EEEE   <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you @rawr, while this solution does work, it is significantly slower than the original commands, this took 19 seconds to process ~400K matches. Any thoughts on how it could be sped up?

Comment: You might get some minimal gains with `vapply` instead of `sapply`, but I think in general base regex is a bit slow.. stringi/stringr are supposed to be faster